# Uploading large video files on background in react native

Tags: react-native

I need to upload large video files in the background.
What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried using this library ([react-native-background-upload](https://github.com/Vydia/react-native-background-upload)). But the problem is, I can't send any other data along with the video file. The API expects the following data:

```js
{
  projectId: number,
  title: string,
  video: file,
};
```

This is the piece of code to send the files with `multipart` using the library:

```js
const options = {
  url: url,
  path: pathToVideoFile,
  method: 'POST',
  field: 'video',
  type: 'multipart',
};
```

Are there any alternatives that I can use? Can [react-native-background-fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch) be used for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in [react-native-background-upload](https://github.com/Vydia/react-native-background-upload)
you can use `parameters` in `options` to send additional data

> Additional form fields to include in the HTTP request. Only used when type: 'multipart

```js
const options = {
  url: url,
  path: pathToVideoFile,
  method: 'POST',
  field: 'video',
  type: 'multipart',
  parameters : {
     key1: "value1",
     key2: "value2",
  }
};
```

you can see all options params here [here](https://github.com/Vydia/react-native-background-upload#startuploadoptions)

Answer (score 1):

you can install [react-native-compressor](https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor) package which is made by me

## Installation

```
yarn add react-native-compressor
```

## Usage

```
import {Video} from 'react-native-compressor';

const headers={
 'Content-Type': '',
}

const uploadResult = await Video.backgroundUpload(
   "http://w.hbu50.com:8080/hello.mp4",
    fileUri,
    {httpMethod: 'PUT', headers},
    (written, total) => {
      onProgress({
        status: 'uploading',
        progress: written / total,
        uploading: true,
      });
    },
  );
```

Comment: How to pass additional parameters in this. API request parameters.